# Altair: Can't get independent 'y' scales with faceted heatmap

Tags: heatmap, facet, altair

I'm working in a jupyter notebook trying to display a sort of adjacency-matrix-like data set in a grouped layout like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mltDA.png) using Altair's `Chart.facet()` method. [This guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57158595) gets me halfway there, but when I try to facet with rows and resolve the y scale as 'independent', the chart comes up as [a tiny box containing no elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTeWH.png).

```py
df = (pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
      .reset_index(drop=True)  # drop string index
      .reset_index()  # add an index column
      .melt(id_vars=['index'], var_name="column")
     )

# To include all the indices and not create NaNs, I add -1 and max(indices) + 1 to the desired bins.
hbins= [-1, 3, 9, 15, 27, 30]
df['hbins'] = pd.cut(df['index'], hbins, labels=range(len(hbins) - 1))
# This was done for the index, but a similar approach could be taken for the columns as well.

df['vbins'] = df.column.replace({'A':'Grp1', 'B':'Grp1', 'C':'Grp2', 'D':'Grp2'})

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('index:O', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('column:O', title=None),
    color="value:Q",
    column=alt.Column("hbins:O", 
                      title=None, 
                      header=alt.Header(labelFontSize=0)
                     ),
    row=alt.Row("vbins:O", 
                      title=None, 
                      header=alt.Header(labelFontSize=0)
                     )
).resolve_scale(
    x="independent",
    y="independent"
).configure_facet(
    spacing=5
)
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Vega or Vega-Lite: when you include ``y="independent"`` in this chart, there is a javascript error visible in the console.

Comment: In what console are you seeing a javascript error? Running the python code in my jupyter notebook doesn't throw an error, nor do I get an error when I copy and paste the compiled Vega into the [online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#).

Comment: I see the error in the javascript console of the browser viewing the jupyter notebook (not in the jupyter notebook itself, because the error is from the javascript, not from the Python). I also see the error in the javascript console when viewing the chart in the vega editor (in the browser console, not in the vega log pane).