# Altair heatmap independent color map calculation per row

Tags: altair

I am trying to plot a heatmap using altair. The idea is that the color mapping is applied independently to each of the rows and not across all the observations. Unfortunately, this is what I get so far.

[image]

As you can see on the graph, you can only see changes in one row, because this is the one with more cases. However, the idea is to apply the mapping for each row and not all together.

This is the code that I have so far:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jlcoto/covid-peru-data/master"
    "/data/limpia/data_limpia_datos_siscovid_2020_05_26.csv",
    parse_dates=["fecha_resultado"],
    dtype={"ubigeo": "string"},
)

evol_departamento = (
    data.groupby(
        ["departamento", pd.Grouper(key="fecha_resultado", freq="D")]
    )[["uuid"]]
    .count()
    .rename(columns={"uuid": "num_casos"})
    .reset_index()
)

alt.Chart(evol_departamento).mark_rect().encode(
    x="monthdate(fecha_resultado)",
    y="departamento:O",
    color=alt.Color("num_casos:Q"),
).resolve_scale(color="independent",)
```

I saw this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122427/altair-cant-get-independent-y-scales-with-faceted-heatmap) about using `resolve_scale`, however it does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: resolve only applies to multi-panel charts. Yours is a single panel chart. The only way to have independent color scale normalizations within a single panel would be to normalize the data within each row, either in pandas or using a calculate transform. If you edit your question to include a full reproducible example (including data), I can add an answer with an example of this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, @jakevdp. I just updated the example to include the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `resolve` functionality only applies across multi-panel charts (facet, concat, repeat, layer, etc.) To adjust the color scale within the encoding for a single chart, the best approach is to use [altair transforms](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/index.html) to compute a normalized version of your data.

Here is an example for your dataset:

```
alt.Chart(evol_departamento).transform_joinaggregate(
    max_casos='max(num_casos)',
    groupby=['departamento']
).transform_calculate(
    num_casos_norm='datum.num_casos / datum.max_casos'
).mark_rect().encode(
    x="monthdate(fecha_resultado)",
    y="departamento:O",
    color=alt.Color("num_casos_norm:Q"),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of using row faceting with opacity for the cases and color for the departments. Although opacity lacks a bit of the contrast.

```py
chart2 = alt.Chart(evol_departamento).mark_rect().encode(
    x="monthdate(fecha_resultado)",
    color=alt.Color("departamento:N", legend=None),
    opacity = alt.Opacity("num_casos:Q", legend=None)
).properties(
    width=800, height=12
).facet(row='departamento:N'
).configure_facet(
    spacing= 0
).configure_view(
    stroke=None
).resolve_scale(
    opacity='independent'
)

chart2
```

I did not immediately found out how to rotate the labels with labelAngle.

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXkNo.png)